# Yii CGridView change controller name (for generating urls)

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, yii-widgets

I have a view displaying company details, and I added a list of orders made by this company (separate model and controller).
Everything works, however the `CGridView` that is used to display the list of orders is rendered (`renderPartial()`) from the company's controller, and because of that, the default controller of the `CGridView` is `company` instead of `order`, that causes all the automatically generated URLs like for the update/delete buttons to be invalid, because they are being generated as `/company/delete?id=` and they should refer to the `order` controller. I went around this by manually creating the URLs for the action buttons like that:

```
$columns[] = array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'buttons' => array(
            'delete' => array(
                'label' => 'Download',
                'url' => 'CController::createUrl("/order/delete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                'options' => array('class' => 'download'),
            ),
        ),  
        'template' => '{delete}',
);
```

But I don't like this approach, as this requires manual creation of every URL. I tried setting the `controller` field of the `CGridView`, but it's read-only.
How can I modify the default controller/model that `CGridView` is working on?

I also see that `CGridView` generates a hidden 'keys' div with IDs of elements, and these keys have `update` URLs with incorrect controller name, so I really need to somehow change the controller `CGridView` is working on, as I don't want to risk it updating entries in wrong controllers.

**Edit**
I tried creating an instance of the controller and use that instance to create the widget:

```
$ctrl = Yii::app()->createController('order')[0];
$ctrl->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', $grid);
```

But even though the owner property (read only) of the created widget is good (`OrderController`), the action URLs are still being generated with the actual path (`/company/`) instead of `/order/`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using relative routes (like `delete`), Yii will use current request context to resolve route. So it does not matter which controller is used to render widget, route of `Yii::app()->controller` will be used as a base for relative routes.

There is not much what you can do in this case - if your widget should not depend on context, you should use absolute routes for URLs:

```
[
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/order/delete",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))',
    // ...
],
```

If you don't want to repeat this in multiple places, you may create widget or helper, which will prepare `CGridView` settings.